# Read substring from QString

Tags: c++, regex, xml, qt

I have a `QString` with this structure:

```
<msg>
    <to>ircellFarzan</to>
    <from>374</from>
    <replied_msg>10</replied_msg>
</msg>example content
```

I just want to know about the value `374` . Any suggestion how to read this value?
Here is my code:

```
if (m_selectedFullContent.contains("<replied_id>"))
{
    //find text between <replied_id> and </replied_id>
}
```

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocument.html

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-xml.html